# word-wrap: break-word не работает в IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

```
div.root_cat a{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #0a79c1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Во всех браузерах слова переносятся, а в IE нет. Как правильно прописать?

Comment: Укажите, о какой версии IE идет речь

Comment: Я пробовал в 11. Но пишут что во всех. Какое кроссбраузерное решение?

Comment: немного устаревшая, но качественная шпаргалка по переносам http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/02/word-wrap.html откройте в IE, потестируйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не работает перенос по двум причинам:

Во-первых, элемент должен иметь вариант отображения отличный от `inline`. Именно этот вариант задан для элемента `a` по умолчанию.
Во-вторых, для элемента должна быть указана ширина.

Пример исправления поведения:

```js
/* С пустым js не работает сниппет */
```

```css
a {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: #0a79c1;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: block
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Оченьдлинноесловобезединогопробела</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло, ширина обязательно и дисплей-блок.
В таблице вылазил длинный текст, без пробелов, из ячейки

```
width: 100%;
word-wrap: break-word;
display: block;
```